# UITableView and indexPathsForSelectedRows

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableView that I have set `allowsMultipleSelection` to YES in storyboard.

**EDIT**

I was wrong about one thing... `[tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows]` does return a NSArray with 1 object in it during `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

However it does not work in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` after I reload the table so it will check which accessory (check mark or not) to apply.

In the original question I was trying to manually select the rows... Apparently that is handled by the tableView itself.. but somewhere along the way it is automatically deselecting my row as I never call `deselectRowAtIndexPath` on it...

**Original Question:**

For some reason when I set the cell to selected it does not change.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
    didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //cell does not update selected property to YES after this next line
    cell.selected = YES;

    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]  
               withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

I suppose I can keep track of the selected index paths myself... but I can swear I used a method that involved `indexPathsForSelectedRows` previously with success...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please post your all codes for this class in pastbean and put your link here we need more information,

and also try:

//in your interface

```
 @interface YourClass (){
 NSInteger _selectedIndex;
 }
```

// cellForRowAtIndexPath: method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  
 *)indexPath
 {
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

// didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
_selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set the `selected` property directly

So instead of

```
cell.selected = YES;
```

Use

```
[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:TheIndexPAth animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom];
```

Comment: tried that as well. Still no luck. I am trying to set it selected so I can call `[tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows]` in a seperate method. Currently that method returns nil because nothing is selecting. It seems like I have done this before in iOS 5 just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try `[cell setSelected:YES animated:YES]`

I'm pretty sure `cell.selected` is read only

Comment: Same result, `[tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows]` returns nil

Comment: using `selectRowAtIndexPath`? yes unfortunately.

Comment: No, it is not read only. @property(nonatomic, getter=isSelected) BOOL selected

Answer (score 0):

A bit unfair since the question changed but.. for me.. the answer is either don't use

```
indexPathsForSelectedRows
```

or don't call

```
reloadTable
```

on your tableView.

I opted for the later, I decorated the accessory in `didSelectRow` and `didDeselectRow` instead of doing it on reload and just never reloading the table.

If someone can come up with a solution that involves both of the above, I will select that answer instead.